# Repeat array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to repeat an array in loop mode. In this way:

A, B; C; D; E, A, B; C; D; E, A, B; C; D; E, A, B; C; D; E, A, B; C; D; E, A, B; C; D; E, A, B; C; D; E

```js
var a = "A;B;C;D;E;";

var b = a.split(';');

for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
{
   $('#ul').append('<li>'+ b[i] +'</li>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul"></ul>
```

But I can not repeat it. I would like to understand the method to use because my real sopo and to create a calendar with the shifts. In practice, once you set a start date the array has to be repeated on the calendar. Example:

array = (A, B, C, D, E):

- 26.08.2016 A
- 27/08/2016 B
- 28.8.2016 C
- 29.08.2016 D
- 08.30.2016 E
- 08.31.2016 A
- 01/09/2016 B
- 09/02/2016 C
- 09.03.2016 D
- 09.04.2016 E

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2td0.jpg)

I hope you get the idea and you have some advice for me.

thank you

example php script

```html
 $data = '03/10/2014';
 $turni = array('sera','pomeriggio','Mattina','Notte','Riposo');

 $n_g_mesi = array(1=>31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);
 list($gg,$mm,$aa) = explode('/', $data);
 $gg = (int)$gg;
 $mm = (int)$mm;
 $n_g_q_mese =  $n_g_mesi[$mm];

 $numero_turni = 10;

 $n = count($turni);
 for($i=0; $i<$numero_turni; $i++){
  echo $data.' '.$turni[$i%$n]."<br />\n";
  $gg = $gg%$n_g_q_mese+1;
if($gg==1){
$mm = $mm%12+1;
if($mm==3 && $aa%4==0 && $n_g_q_mese==28){ // se l'anno è bisestile
 $mm = 2;
 $gg = $n_g_q_mese = 29;
}
else{
 $n_g_q_mese = $n_g_mesi[$mm];
 if($mm==1)
  $aa++;
}
}
  $data = str_pad($gg,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).'/'.str_pad($mm,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).'/'.$aa;
 }
```

Comment: So loop over it again?

Comment: Found your code snippet looping like a champ, may I know where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to repeat things multiple times, than loop multiple times

Nested loop

```
var b = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
for(var i=0;i<3;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<b.length;j++) {
        console.log(b[j]);
    }
}
```

or Loop the number of times and use a Modulus based on length or the array.

```
var b = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
for(var i=0;i<20;i++) {
    console.log(b[i%b.length]);
}
```

Comment: The second example is perfect. But now to match the letters on a date how can I do? I had done with php but with javascript are impractical, maybe you can take a cue?

Comment: I have no idea how letters correspond to the date.

Comment: the letters must be added to dates. I put in my first post I made in php script.

Comment: I have no idea about your other posts.... We only know what you posted in this question orginally. This answers the details you gave in the question. If you needed a better answer, you need to add details....

Comment: Excuse for my English. It earlier message I wanted to say that I have entered in my first post of this thread an example of script in php, where I can do what I want to accomplish in JavaScript also here you can see the script running [Link script ](http://www.turnips.it/1.php)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to realize this is to use nested loop

```js
var a = "A;B;C;D;E";

var b = a.split(';');

var counter = 3; // number of iterations
for (var j = 0; j < counter; j++) {
  for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
     $('#ul').append('<li>'+ b[i] +'</li>');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = "A;B;C;D;E";

var b = a.split(';');

for (var c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
{
   $('#ul').append('<li>'+ b[i] +'</li>');
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul"></ul>
```

Just add a nested loop.  Change 5 to the number of times you want it to loop.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = "A;B;C;D;E;";

var b = a.split(';');
var times=5;
for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
{
   $('#ul').append('<li>'+ b[i] +'</li>');
   if(i==4 && times>0)  // 4 here otherwise use b.length as in limiting array
   {
      i=0;
      times--;
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul" style="list-style:none"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use modulo and `map` over the collection of `#ul`'s.

`ARRAY[DATE % ARRAY.length]` will return the next sequence in the array and start from 0 once it reaches the end.

In the below example I use idx to determine letter, but you could pull it from some identifier in the `ul` object.

```js
var a = "A;B;C;D;E";

var b = a.split(';');

array_of_uls.map(function(ul, idx)
    {
       ul.append('<li>'+ b[idx % b.length] +'</li>');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul"></ul>
```

Comment: Your example stops at the 31 of the month, however I would like it to continue. In practice the script will be used for a business turnario. So the untente by date inserted can see that the shift s waiting on a certain date.

Comment: @Sixdas Get all your `#ul` into a collection then map over the collection and apply the modulo. Example is shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this job as follows;

```js
var str = "A;B;C;D;E;";

myList.appendChild(str.repeat(5)
                      .split(";")
                      .slice(0,-1)
                      .reduce((frag,text) => {var myLi = document.createElement("li");
                                              myLi.textContent = text;
                                              frag.appendChild(myLi);
                                              return frag;
                                             }, document.createDocumentFragment()));
```

```html
<ul id="myList"></ul>
```